# What is better way to create datetime object where just date needs to change?

Tags: python, datetime

- I need to create a `datetime` from a different `datetime` object, where the `day` needs to change.
- I also need to preserve the `tzinfo`.

This is what I do

```
day = 16
today = datetime.today()

print 'today:', today

from_date = datetime(today.year, today.month, day, today.hour,
                     today.minute, today.second, today.microsecond,
                     today.tzinfo)
```

When I run this, I get

```
today: 2013-06-01 09:19:37.138404
from_date: 2013-06-16 09:19:37.138404
```

I want to know if there is better pythonic way to do this

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You use the [`datetime.replace()` method](http://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html#datetime.datetime.replace) on the instance:

```
from_date = today.replace(day=day)
```

> Return a datetime with the same attributes, except for those attributes given new values by whichever keyword arguments are specified.